# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis (All parenthesis are there!)

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a table in oracle and keep getting the error. 
Here is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE employee 
( 
     employeenumber INT(2) NOT NULL, 
     firstname      CHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
     lastname       CHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
     department     CHAR(35) NOT NULL, 
     position       CHAR(35) NOT NULL, 
     supervisor     INT(2) NOT NULL, 
     officephone    CHAR(12) NOT NULL, 
     emailaddress   CHAR(100) NOT NULL 

);
```

Can anyone shine some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: consider VARCHAR2 over CHAR. With a CHAR(100) for email address, oracle will always use 100 characters to store my email address, which only needs 15 characters.

Comment: And in that case, consider VARCHAR(370), since email addresses can be longer than 100. On average you will still use less space than with a CHAR(100). :)

Answer (score 2):

The `int` (`integer`) data type specifier does not take an argument. So remove `(2)` from `int(2)`, ...etc. If you need to specify the number of digits, then use `number(2)` instead. `int` or `integer` (without a number in parenthesis) is supported, and is [equivalent to `number(38)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00213)

See the relevant syntax diagrams for data types in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021):

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you used SQL*Plus (instead of a GUI you do use), you'd see the culprit:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE employee
  2  (
  3       employeenumber INT(2) NOT NULL,
  4       firstname      CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  5       lastname       CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  6       department     CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  7       position       CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  8       supervisor     INT(2) NOT NULL,
  9       officephone    CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
 10       emailaddress   CHAR(100) NOT NULL
 11  );
     employeenumber INT(2) NOT NULL,
                       *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL>
```

Got it? Remove INT's size.

Apart from that, you most probably do **NOT** want to use `CHAR` datatype, but `VARCHAR2`. `CHAR` will right pad all values with spaces, up to column's full length and cause problems.

```
SQL> create table employee
  2  (
  3       employeenumber int not null,
  4       firstname      varchar2(30) not null,
  5       lastname       varchar2(100) not null,
  6       department     varchar2(35) not null,
  7       position       varchar2(35) not null,
  8       supervisor     int not null,
  9       officephone    varchar2(12) not null,
 10       emailaddress   varchar2(100) not null
 11  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: actually our parser (SQL Developer GUI) shows the problem even before you run the statement

Comment: That's what I'm complaining about, @Jeff. SQL Developer says "Error starting at line : 1 in command -" but that's less than descriptive. SQL*Plus - with an asterisk - shows exactly where is the error, pointing to `(2)` in `INT(2)`

Comment: if you use the gui and know what to look for, you see the error before you even go to run the code, and we have links to the docs so you can get it right https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/littlefoot.png

Comment: Aha. I apologize, @Jeff, I completely misunderstood what you were saying.

Comment: no worries, and we'd show what SQL*Plus shows, but the jdbc driver doesn't offer that feature

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's NUMBER not INTEGER.

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
     employeenumber NUMBER(2) NOT NULL, 
     firstname      CHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
     lastname       CHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
     department     CHAR(35) NOT NULL, 
     position       CHAR(35) NOT NULL, 
     supervisor     NUMBER(2) NOT NULL, 
     officephone    CHAR(12) NOT NULL, 
     emailaddress   CHAR(100) NOT NULL 

); 
Table created.
```